# Find a universe and a predicate that satisfy the following formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Consider the formula
F =∀x ∃y ∃z (¬(x=y) ∧ ¬P(x,y) ∧ ¬(x=z) ∧ P(x,z)).

I have to find a universe $U$ which cardinality is given by n, while n >= 3. Furthermore I should find a predicate $P: U^{2} \rightarrow \{0,1\} $ which satisfies the given formula F. The universe should be defined in terms of n, meaning that if I would tell you n = 5 everything should work. I tried several  things but don't understand how to define this universe in terms of n.

Comment: Are you sure that $n \geq 3$ and not $n > 3$?

Comment: yes, but I think I found a solution

Comment: OK, you can write it, it could be useful for someone else as well. Otherwise, I have a solution essentially inspired by bipartite graphs and I'll write it.

Comment: A finite structure with $n = 3$ can be given by $U = \{a, b, c\}, I(P) = \{\langle a, c \rangle, \langle b, c \rangle, \langle c, a \rangle\}$ -- something like a one-directional circle of three elements. Note sure about a real-life example of $P$, though.

Comment: Already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852379/find-a-predicate-and-a-7niverse-for-the-formula)

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852350/logic-question-predicate-logic)

Answer (score 1):

I actually now found a solution:
Consider $U = \{n-n, n-(n-1), ..., n-1 \;|\; n \in N, \; n \geq 3 \}$
with $$ P(a, b) =\begin{cases}1,\;x + 1 \equiv y \;(mod\; 3)\\0,\; otherwise\end{cases} $$

Comment: Good intuition! Pay attention to typos. You can simplify you structure, saying that two numbers in $U$ are in the relation $P$ if they have the same parity, i.e. $P(a,b)$ if and only if $a \equiv b \mod 2$.